# Append 2 data frames into 1 new data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine data in 2 different dataframes into 1 new dataframe and both data frames having their columns jumbled up.

I would like to combine the data so that df1 and df2 values are in DF3 where 'Ref' values from df1 and df2 appear under df3 'Ref' column, 
'Amount' values from df1 and df2 appear in df3 'Amount' column and so on

df1

```
Ref Amount  Receiver    Payer   Month
1   2000    X           Chris   Jan
2   2222    Y           Jinnn   Jan
3   3002    Z           Chhhh   Jan
4   10000   ZZ          BBBB    Jan
5   25233   ZZZ         CCCCC   Jan
```

df2

```
Ref Month   Receiver    Payer   Amount
1   Feb      111         AAA    3000
2   Feb      222         BBB    4000
3   Feb      333         CCC    5000
4   Feb      444         DDD    6000
5   Feb      555         EEE    6000
```

df 3

```
Ref Amount  Receiver    Payer   Month
1   2000           X    Chris   Jan
2   2222           Y    Jinnn   Jan
3   3002           Z    Chhhh   Jan
4   10000         ZZ    BBBB    Jan
5   25233        ZZZ    CCCCC   Jan
1   3000         111    AAA     Feb
2   4000         222    BBB     Feb
3   5000         333    CCC     Feb
4   6000         444    DDD     Feb
5   6000         555    EEE     Feb
```

Tried the code below but I received results which I'm not expecting. There are additional columns in the new data frame which I do not want.

Is concat the correct method to use?

Thanks for the guidance

I have tried to code using the logic below.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Month1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Month2.xlsx")

df_3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the parameter `sort=False` like this:

`df_3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True,sort=False)`

Output:

```
    Ref Amount  Receiver    Payer   Month
0   1   2000    X   Chris   Jan
1   2   2222    Y   Jinnn   Jan
2   3   3002    Z   Chhhh   Jan
3   4   10000   ZZ  BBBB    Jan
4   5   25233   ZZZ CCCCC   Jan
5   1   3000    111 AAA     Feb
6   2   4000    222 BBB     Feb
7   3   5000    333 CCC     Feb
8   4   6000    444 DDD     Feb
9   5   6000    555 EEE     Feb
```